# Denseness of the set .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the set $$X=\{x\in[0,1]:x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{10^{n}},a_{n}\in\{3,5\}\}$$ How to show that the set $X$ is not dense in $[0,1]?$ 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is a closed proper set: it cannot be dense. Another way: $(0.21, 0.22)$ is an open set disjoint from $X$, so $X$ is not dense.

Answer (score 2):

Every element in $X$ is at least $1/3,$ so no sequence in X can converge to a point in $[0,1/3).$